# Выборка из базы по времени

Tags: python, django

В модели есть поле `DateTimeField()`, в базе сохраняется значение вида `2015-09-21 17:37:11`.

Как сделать выборку по последним нескольким часам?
Например, чтобы в выборку попали только значения за последние 3 часа.

Answer (score 2):

В общем так можно сделать:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

delta = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=4)  
articles = Article.objects.filter(date_time__gte=delta)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Тут](http://djbook.ru/rel1.4/topics/db/queries.html#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters) все доступно, накладывайте фильтры на ваш `QuerySet()` цепочкой

```
Modelname.objects.exclude(AttributeName=datetime(год, месяц, день) #меньше чем текущая на 3 часа
... ).filter(AttributeName=datetime.now()) #текущая дата
```